# Using X-grid in Material v5

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I started building an react app using the new v5 alpha [material-ui](https://next.material-ui.com/)
According to their documentation 'The data grid components are supporting v5 and v4'.
So I installed the X-grid and when I import the X-grid I get this error:

./node_modules/@material-ui/x-grid/dist/index-esm.js

Module not found: Can't resolve '@material-ui/styles' in 'C:\Users\remusp\Desktop\React\material\node_modules@material-ui\x-grid\dist'

Does anyone know how to make this work together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so you can install material/styles

```
npm install @material-ui/styles
```

sometimes the packages comes splited, so if you will use all material-ui install all lib